# Proguard error: "Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first"

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

Since upgrading to android gradle plugin 3.0.1 I am getting following error:

```
Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForProductionRelease FAILED

Problem is: I don't see any warning in my log.

I also ran the build with -i flag and I am getting following (big) log:
https://gist.github.com/stoefln/b5e5e899c73b52d8065a5daeead716b3

Any ideas are very welcome!

Comment: You should run your build with the -i flag and add -verbose to your proguard rules to get more output. The warning should be printed right after reading the library which has the problem.

Answer (score 13):

This is because in your dependencies there are multiples rxjava implicit dependencies with different version.

From this log:

```
Reading program jar [/Users/steph/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.reactivex/rxjava/1.2.5/b423532b5a3c949cbb799468f83bf566032fe98d/rxjava-1.2.5.jar] (filtered)
```

and

```
Reading library jar [/Users/steph/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.reactivex/rxjava/1.2.3/7fe1a94c1aeb958acc876fe616922cc191f3222c/rxjava-1.2.3.jar] (filtered)
```

You can see that in your app, there is 2 version of rxjava: **1.2.3** and **1.2.5**

One of your dependencies, android-rxlocationsettings, is using rxjava 1.2.5, you can take a look at its [build.gradle](https://github.com/JetradarMobile/android-rxlocationsettings/blob/master/rxlocationsettings/build.gradle):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
  compile 'pl.charmas.android:android-reactive-location:0.10@aar'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
  compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.5'
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 25
  buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
  }
}
```

So, you need to exclude it either using exclude from dependency:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile ('com.github.jetradarmobile:android-rxlocationsettings:1.1.0') {
    exclude group: "io.reactivex", name: "rxjava"
  }
  ...
}
```

or using configuration:

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: "io.reactivex", module:"rxjava"
}
```

Comment: can you please also add how you found out about the conflict?

Comment: @stoefln: you can found it from `Note: duplicate definition of library class [rx.BackpressureOverflow$Strategy]`. `rx.***` is part of rxjava. Btw, you also have another duplicate library, it's probably android httpclient.

every line with `Note: duplicate definition of library class ` is telling you that you have duplicate dependencies whether explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. And how did you find out which libraries are referencing rx?

Comment: It's simple, if you try founding for `rx.` occurances in your log, you will found out something like this: `Note: duplicate definition of library class [rx.plugins.RxJava.**`. Which means rx.** is the package of rxjava. Then go to the rxjava github to make sure. There you will found out that the package is for rxjava version 1.

Comment: sorry, that's not what I meant. Let me rephrase the question: how did you find out that rx is used in the rxLocationSettings library? Did you use `./gradlew dependencies` for that?

Comment: because there are many libraries, you can't go through all of them and check their dependencies

Comment: Yes, you're correct. You can use `./gradlew app:dependencies` to see the dependencies tree. Or you can get a quick glance of your dependencies tree in your project by selecting the Project toolbar on the left then change Android to Project. You can see the library from `External Libraries`.

Answer (score 11):

The only thing that worked for me was this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55559396/293918) by @Moti Bartov

```
-ignorewarnings
```

At the end of `proguard-rules.pro`

Answer (score 1):

To view the warnings add the option `-verbose` to your proguard file and grep the warnings from the gradle output:

```
./gradlew -i clean assemble<buildtype> | grep -i "warning"
```

where build type can be Release or any other build type you defined which contains the proguard configuration.

Answer (score 0):

just use -dontwarn in proguard-rules.pro like below

-dontwarn com.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, in my case I checked the logs for warnings if you find any related to class reference, it indicates you need to clean build the project.

run `gradlew clean` followed by

> gradlew build

or combined `gradlew clean build`

[Build Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Irf2t.png)

[Warnings to look out for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGjb8.png)

Answer (score 0):

**try this** (it's work for me)

I have also issue with pro guard but i found following code from git hub more useful.

add this line on proguard-rules.pro

```
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
```

Answer (score 0):

Juste add ignore warnings in proguard: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59428966/7308789